# External Hard Drive Sometimes Clicks - Time to change?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a 160GB Maxtor external hard drive. Recently I noticed that it makes loud clicking noises when I access data on it. This does not happen ALL the time though.

Does this mean that the drive is on its way out and that failure is imminent? Obviously I should back up data off this drive but is it nolonger fit for use?

Thanks.

Comment: its because its a maxtor, they click normally, and they normally dont work.  I have a 2.5in external that clicks and has been for 6 months or so.  it gets banged around alot so i'm surprised its lived as long as it has.  I have a spare for when it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loud clicking noises on a hard drive is VERY bad. So to answer the question......it's no longer fit for use.

Comment: Ok thank you, so any clicking on a device even for a fraction of a second is not good at all? Meaning you know it needs replacing if oyu hear it.

Comment: Given that hard drives are relatively inexpensive these days...I wouldn't gamble losing data on a 160GB drive you could replace for maybe $70....
Anytime I hear an audible click from a hard drive...I find it worrying...

Comment: Ok thank you. Thankfully I have a relatively new 1TB drive to copy the stuff over. Ah the idea of backing up your backups!

Answer (score -1):

If you still can access the data in it, you must consider yourself lucky. You should back it up immediately and get rid of it.